# Usage of fseek and feof

Tags: c, fseek

I this code is used for reading the text file in reverse order. And it successful does, displaying the original content of file and the reversed content of file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()  {

    int count = 0, ch = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    if( (fp = fopen("file.txt", "r")) == NULL )    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("\tINPUT FILE\n");
    printf("\n");
    while(!feof(fp))    {
        if((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)  {
            printf("%c", ch);
            count ++;
        }
    }
    feof(fp);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\tREVERSED INPUT FILE\n");
    printf("\n");
    while(count)    {
        fseek(fp, -2, SEEK_CUR);
        printf("%c", getc(fp));
        count--;
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

But when i replaced, this piece of code

```
while(!feof(fp))    {
   if((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF)  {
       printf("%c", ch);
       count ++;
   }
}
```

by

```
fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END); or  feof(fp);
```

Basically i just went till end of file and directly without printing the original contents of file and tried printing the reversed content of file.
But for it does not print the reversed content filed either !!! it just display blank. Why is this happening ??

NOTE: `fseek(fp, -2, SEEK_CUR);` Have done this (in another while loop) as getc(fp) moves fp forward by one so need to rewind it back by two, also initially it will be pointing to EOF

What is happening here? Can any one please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It breaks because the second loop is `while (count)`, and `count` is zero if you haven't read through the file first while incrementing it. You can use `ftell` to obtain the equivalent of `count` in this case.

P. S. `feof(fp)` only tests whether `fp` is at end-of-file, it does not make it seek to EOF, so the line `feof(fp)` basically does nothing since you aren't using the return value.

Answer (score 1):

As @Arkku already showed, when you replace the `while` loop with `fseek(SEEK_END)`, `count` will not be incremented.

To fix this, you can use [`ftell`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftell.3.html) after `fseek`, which returns the file length

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
count = ftell(fp);
```

Now the file will be printed backwards.